# Prove Directional Derivative Exists For All Unit Vectors

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives, partial-derivative

I'm pretty stuck on the following problem.

> Define $f: R^2 \rightarrow R$ by
> $$f(x,y) = \frac{xy^2}{x^2+y^2} \quad\text{ if }\quad (x,y) \neq (0,0),$$
> $$f(x,y) = 0 \quad\quad\quad\text{ if }\quad\quad (x,y) =(0,0).$$
> Prove $D_uf$ exists for all $u$.

So I know that this is the directional derivative, and that $u$ can be any unit vector.

But there are infinite possibilities for $u$, so how can I show the derivative exists for all of them?

Comment: You can't check and confirm one by one that each and every unit vector works, as you say. So the standard thing to do (this applies all throughout mathematics, mind you) is to take an _arbitrary_ unit vector, and show that it definitely works no matter which one you pick.

Comment: I suppose you mean "the directional derivative *at the origin* $\;(0,0)\;$ exists in all directions..."? And then (HUGE) hint: that function is differentiable at the origin (why?) .

Comment: @DonAntonio Thanks! No, the question just says it exists, not specifically at the origin. And it's not differentiable at the origin though. The next part of the problem says "Show f is not differentiable at (0,0)."

Comment: Perhaps these can help you. https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2968112/show-that-for-all-unit-vector-u-the-directional-derivative-partial-uf0-0?rq=1 OR https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/372070/show-that-fracx3x2y2-is-not-differentiable-at-0-0-even-though-al?rq=1

Comment: @AnuragA Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $u = (a,b)$ and $\|u\| = 1$.

According to the definition of directional derivative, it results that
\begin{align*}
D_{u}f(0,0) & = \lim_{t\to 0}\frac{f(0 + ta, 0 + tb) - f(0,0)}{t} =\frac{ab^{2}}{a^{2} + b^{2}} = ab^{2}
\end{align*}

since $\|u\| = 1$, and we are done.

Hopefully this helps!

Comment: Yes thank you! I was confused haha makes a lot of sense.